# VB.NET: Get native language name from LCID

Tags: vb.net, culture

I would like to get the native language name (for example "Deutsch (Deutschland)") for a given LCID.
So far I have only seen example where I had to set the CurrentThread's culture to this culture. 
I am looking for a solution to it without having to set the CurrentThread's culture.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without setting `this new culture` (whose LCID is provided) to your current thread's culture you go with this way:

```
 Dim NativeName As String=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(LCID_HERE).NativeName
```